# Sticky TCP sessions with IOT sensors

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Can anyone help with the correct HA PROXY configuration for TCP IOT Sensors

Each IOT sensor has a sim card, and reports as IP:port
So most sensors look like they are on same IP but different port (when looking at netstat)

I need to be able to load balance, with sticky tcp session for each IOT sensor so its only creates 1 tcp session and continues to send its data (unless it gets disconnected), but based on IP/Port.

Everything I've seen refers to a cookie, but we cannot write cookies to IOT hardware.
I also need the balance mode to be least connections as to not overload one server.

Comment: Do you want one ongoing TCP connection ("only creates 1 tcp session") or do you want successive TCP connections to be directed to the same backend ("Sticky TCP sessions")?

Comment: when the IOT device creates a connection, it needs to stick to that one server, if it disconnects and reconnects, it can goto any server, but once connected it must stick with that server, currently it just round robins and when it hits the new server, it has to create the tcp connection again

Comment: An open TCP connection is to a specific backend - it does not switch backends while remaining open. If backend is changing, it means the connection is being closed (or a second one opened etc.).

Comment: ok, so it should automatically do this? thats interesting, i'll give it another try, but the last time i checked it was bouncing between the 2

Comment: Why are you not using IPv6?

Comment: IPv6 for which part? pointing IOT Devices to server? what advantage does v6 have?